# .NET MVC solution with DAL project: where to put custom validation attributes (server-side and client-side)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

.NET MVC application, using Identity and EF code-first.
In it I have a CustomValidations.cs where I have written some custom validation attributes: some of them contains both server-side and client-side validation. Both models and viewmodels use these validation attributes. (client-side validation is done by implementing IClientValidatable and adding its method GetClientValidationRules).

For example (this resides in a folder CustomAttributes/CustomValidations.cs in the MVC project):

```
namespace MyApp.CustomAttributes {

    public class RequiredIfSomething : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {
        public RequiredIfSomething() { }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {
            //server-side validation code here
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {
            // client-side validation code here. 
            yield return rule;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to separate the solution in different projects. I have started by creating a class library project (MyApp.DAL) for the DAL layer, and moved all my entity framework entities, dbcontext (ApplicationDbContext, which is an IdentityDbContext) and migrations folder from the MVC project to the new project, added references in the MVC project and modified namespaces etc.
So now, the MVC project uses the DAL project.

All this seems to be working, but now I have a problem with my custom validators:
I guess these validations (or at least, some of them) should reside in the DAL project, as I am decorating the models properties with them. But then, I would have in DAL project not only server-side validation, but also client-side validation that I feel should be specific to mvc (and thus, should not reside in the DAL project)...

What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, this is solved using viewmodels in the web layer and your base EF models in the data access layer. Your custom validators to validate client input, etc will go on your view models and reside in the web layer. Your custom validators for your models (generally to protect the integrity of data being inserted into the db) will go on your EF models and reside in the data access layer. There are a few mapping librariers to helps translate between raw EF models and viewmodels (auto mapper probably being the most common) if you're not used to doing this.